# VBA sql query using server, database name and table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-word, adodb

I am trying to get via VBA, to a ms SQL server database to execute a query and out put the results to a Microsoft Word table.

The database is on a server. 
The code is below:

```
Sub SQLConnect2()
    Debug.Print "Start"

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String
    Dim strFirstName As String

    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Server;Trusted_connection=yes;"
    Debug.Print ConnectionString

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open ConnectionString

    StrQuery = "USE Database SELECT TOP 10 name as Title FROM table"


    rs.Open StrQuery, cn

    Debug.Print StrQuery
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount

End Sub
```

This however gives me run-time errors as it says the record set is closed, I believe this is because the query doesn't work, however when I copy and paste the query into SSMS it does work as expected.

I believe it might be due to it connecting to the server and then not using the database in the *use* statement.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
James

Comment: If you are going to have multiple statements you need to terminate each statement with a semicolon. But in this case I don't see why you need multiple statements. If you need to select data from another database than the connection was opened for you can simply use three part naming. "select top 10 name from Database.schema.table" --and don't forget the order by so you know which 10 rows you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change your connection string to include the database name:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=YourDataBase; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

and remove the Use Database in your query.

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/